# error: must set personality to get -x option

Tags: bash

Why this command works:

```
ps -ax | grep mongo
```

but when I try set it to variable:

```
ubuntu# command='ps -ax | grep mongo'

ubuntu# echo $command
ps -ax | grep mongo
```

It gives me error, when calling:

```
ubuntu# $command
error: must set personality to get -x option

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

Comment: Any reason not to use [`pgrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pgrep.1.html)?

Comment: @muru ok, thank you: `# command='pgrep mongo -la'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't execute a shell variable. You need to explicitly turn the $command variable into a command. The easiest way to do so is with the `eval` command. So: `eval $command` will work.